# Questions about use(d) to go

Tags: semi-modals

Which one is correct, or are all the sentences correct?
3rd sentence made me confuse.

> 1- I didn't use to go swimming a lot.
>   2- I used not to go swimming a lot.
>   3- I didn't used to go swimming a lot.

Comment: I don't think #3 is grammatical. Phonetically, though, there's not much difference between "use to go" and "used to go," so that might be an [eggcorn](http://grammarist.com/mondegreens/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentences #1 and #2 are correct grammatically.  'didn't use to go' and 'used not to go' can be used interchangeably, without any difference in meaning. However, the latter is fairly formal.

As for the sentence #3, though some people also use 'did not used to', it's not usually considered to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

You will hear #3 in real speech, but it should be like #1:

> I didn't use to go swimming a lot.

because with *do + X*, X has to be the plain form.  There is no such thing like *do + { past participle }* like there is with *be* or *have*.

Your second example should be:

> I used to not go swimming a lot.

because if you use *not* with a verb, and that verb is not *be* or *have*, then you have to use *do* with it.

Comment: I think.  I used not to go swimming a lot, is grammatical.

Comment: British English:
 You used not to fuss like this.